# xpages access the local address book and other address book

Tags: xpages

There is an XPages application which is running both in Notes Client and on browser.

Let say I have 2 `xe:namePicker`s:

```
<xe:namePicker id="namePicker1" for="djTextarea5">
    <xe:this.dataProvider>
                <xe:dominoNABNamePicker groups="false"
                            nameList="peopleByLastName" addressBookDb="names.nsf"
                            addressBookSel="db-name">
                </xe:dominoNABNamePicker>
    </xe:this.dataProvider>
</xe:namePicker>
```

and ( this is the Company Address Book )

```
<xe:namePicker id="namePicker2" for="djTextarea5">
        <xe:this.dataProvider>
                <xe:dominoNABNamePicker groups="false" nameList="peopleByLastName adressBookDb="OurServer/Company!!names.nsf"
                                        addressBookSel="db-name">
                    </xe:dominoNABNamePicker>
        </xe:this.dataProvider>
  </xe:namePicker>
```

If I understood correctly, the first namePicker isn't accessing the local address book for the users which accesses the application, but the names.nsf from the server.

my question: What server? Is it the  (Company) `names.nsf` ( which lays on `OurServer/Company` ) ? So are there some differences between the 2 namePickers? I thought the 1st one is referring to the (each) address local book, but I guess I'm wrong.

Any explanations will be appreciated

Comment: Just a side note, you are using two name pickers for one text field. You do know that you can use the namePickerAggregator to have multiple sources feed into one control, right?

Comment: @Greg Thanks for feedback. Yes, indeed, I learned about the namePickerAggregator. In this question, I just added 2 examples regarding ( especially ) the addressBookDb parameter. I'm looking just for some explanation for a better understanding.

Comment: I am unsure, and am not going to put this as an answer, but I am fairly certain that this depends on the context in which the program is running.  If you it is run on the server, than the "" server would be....the server.  If it is a XPiNC running on the client, then "" would be the Notes Client.  Don't quote me though.

Comment: At what are you referring by "" ( server ) ? Let say I use: addressBookDb="names.nsf". So, if I run the XPiNC application in the Notes Client => the current user' local address book. And, if I run it on a browser => the address book of ... ?

Comment: i just meant the server part is blank, names.nsf = <blank>!!namesnsf = @DbName() -["","names.nsf"] But since I am not certain, i should probably just delete these two comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `addressBookDb="names.nsf"` you refer to the "local" address book.

If application runs in **XPiNC** then "local" is user's Notes client. The "names.nsf" is then user's personal address book.

If application runs in **browser** then code gets executed on server and from servers perspective "lokal" is server's data directory and therefore "names.nsf" refers to companies address book on server.

With `adressBookDb="OurServer/Company!!names.nsf"` you refer to server's address book no matter where application is running.

*Side note:* there is database property in Notes 9 which causes execution of XPages on **server** even if they are called from **XPiNC**. In this case "names.nsf" would refer always to companies address book on server.

Comment: And yes, indeed, I'm using Notes v.9. Could you tell me the exact property described?